# What's the equivalent code for join table with multiple rows?

Tags: c#, epicorerp

I have following code which is working perfectly but when the condition is only join table having single row. How to achieve with join table having multiple rows?

```
foreach (var a in ttTableA.Where(r => r.RowMod == "U"))
{
     var b = Db.TableB.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Company == callContextClient.CurrentCompany);
     b.Field1 = a.Field1;
}
```

The code below works fine but I'm just curious could it achieve better by using single line code as example above? May be is by using `ToList()` or something to replace `FirstOrDefault`?

```
foreach (var a in ttTableA.Where(r => r.RowMod == "U"))
 {
     foreach (var b in (from row in Db.TableB.With(LockHint .UpdLock) where row.Company == Session.CompanyID
     select row))
     {
          b.Field1 = a.Field1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a .ToList() to your second query like this:

```
foreach (var a in ttTableA.Where(r => r.RowMod == "U"))
{
    foreach (var b in (
        from row in Db.TableB.With(LockHint.UpdLock)
        where row.Company == Session.CompanyID
        select row).ToList())
    {
        b.Field1 = a.Field1;
    }
}
```

This means the Linq query will return all the records from the database in one trip to the SQL database (all of them locked) in an IEnumerable rather than an IQueryable which would be queried separately in each loop.

---

Incidentally in Epicor ERP you should also write the following instead of the first line:

```
foreach (var a in ttTableA.Where(r => r.Updated))
```

as IceRow implements properties for Updated, Added, Deleted and Unchanged which don't have the case and culture sensitivity that the "U", "A", "D" and "" equivalents have.